# E: Package 'bluez' has no installation candidate

Tags: package-management, bluetooth, ppa

I am using Ubuntu 19.10 and I was trying to update my bluetooth. So I added a PPA and tried to update, but I am getting the following error:

```
Unable to download updates:
failed to refresh cache: E: The repository 'http://ppa.launchpadd.net/bluetooth/~
```

I removed that PPA and now I don't get this error.

Actually, I wasn't aware of it and I thought that removing bluetooth and reinstalling it will fix the error. So I purged all bluetooth and utils.
I added `bluez` PPA and installed using `snap install bluez`.

But my bluetooth is not working. Maybe uninstalling all the utils is causing the problem. So now if I do `sudo apt install bluez` I get this error:

```
E: Package 'bluez' has no installation candidate
```

It seems that I need to install bluetooth from scratch along with its dependencies.

I tried:

```
sudo service bluetooth enable
```

It says:

```
bluetooth: unrecognized service
```

I also tried:

```
sudo service bluetooth start
```

It says:

```
Failed to start bluetooth.service: Unit bluetooth.service not found
```

Comment: `bluez` ([official site](http://www.bluez.org/)) is installed by default in Ubuntu 19.10.

Comment: maybe I had removed it, I installed it again. But I am having another issue now. Devices connects and disconnects immediately.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I seems you are a bit confused about package management.

> So I added a PPA and tried to update, but I am getting the following error:
>
> ```
> Unable to download updates:
> failed to refresh cache: E: The repository 'http://ppa.launchpadd.net/bluetooth/~
> ```

You haven't added the complete error output and you don't show us the PPA you used, but I can see that you have mistyped a double "d" at the end of "launchpad". A wrong PPA (maybe one that does not contain a package for your version of Ubuntu) or this mistyping is probably the reason why you are getting an error while updating. As you found out, removing the invalid PPA makes the error disappear.

> I added `bluez` PPA and installed using `snap installl bluez`.

Again, you don't say what PPA you added, but you wouldn't need to add one, since `bluez` is already at the default Eoan repository. Furthermore, you don't even use the PPA you added, because you installed the snap version of `bluez`. In general, PPAs and snaps have different repositories and are installed with different tools. `apt` is used to install packages from the Ubuntu repositories and PPAs and `snap` to install snaps.

To reinstall `bluez`:

- First uninstall the snap package you installed:

  ```
  snap remove bluez
  ```
- Then remove the PPA you added:

  ```
  sudo add-apt-repository --remove <name-of-ppa>
  ```

  `<name-of-ppa>` is the name of the PPA you added (something like `ppa:bluetooth/bluez` or whatever you used).
- Make sure that `bluez` apt package is removed:

  ```
  sudo apt purge bluez
  ```
- Install `bluez` again:

  ```
  sudo apt install bluez
  ```
- Restart your computer.

Comment: There was a problem, somehow the repos got uncheced on software center, so it that's why I was getting `package has no installing candidate`. For incomplete error that was my fault, sorry. Now if you can help why It disconnect immediately after connecting.

Comment: @SujeetAgrahari Please ask another question for your disconnection problem providing more details about it.

Answer (score 0):

Try install using snap

```
$ sudo apt update
$ sudo apt install snapd
```

and then install bluez

```
$ snap install bluez
```